# Javascript - Images not cycling/rotating

Tags: javascript, image

I'm working on a script to rotate/cycle through images in javascript while respecting a limit on the amount of times it cycles through the images. What I have is below:

```
<a id="imageurl"><img id="Rotating1" border="0"></img></a>

<script language="JavaScript">

var delay = 3000; //6000 = change to next image after 6 seconds
var cycles = 2;
var currentCycle = 0;

function RotateImages(Start, delay)
{
    var a = new Array("frown.gif","grim.gif","smile.gif", "bomb.gif");
    var c = new Array("url1", "url2", "url3", "url4");
    var b = document.getElementById('Rotating1');
    var d = document.getElementById('imageurl');
    var totalCycles = cycles * a.length;
//  alert ("currentCycle: " + currentCycle);
//  alert ("totalCycles: " + totalCycles);

        if (Start>=a.length) 
            Start=0;
        b.src = a[Start];
        d.href = c[Start];

        if (currentCycle < totalCycles) {
            window.setTimeout("RotateImages(" + (Start+1) + ")", delay);
            currentCycle++;
        }
}

RotateImages(0, delay);

</script>
```

The script acts like it's working when I uncomment the alert boxes. When I comment them out, the rotation seems to stop. Any ideas on what is really going on and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "acts like it's working"? Do you mean it actually works, or you see the alerts, but it isn't working fully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps you would like to change this line:

```
window.setTimeout("RotateImages(" + (Start+1) + ")", delay);
```

into:

```
window.setTimeout("RotateImages(" + (Start+1) + ", " + delay + ")", delay);
```

so that the next time RotateImages is called, it will keep the delay.

Answer (score 1):

One fundamental issue to take into consideration is with `setTimeout`. The first parameter can be a reference to a function, whether it be an actual reference or a string reference, but you cant pass parameters along with it.

To do what you want, you need to pass a anonymous function to setTimeout. Also, Riyono is right that you should also pass the `delay`

`setTimeout(function(){ RotateImages(Start++, delay) }, delay);`

As far as your alert issue, I don't know what to tell you. But I know that the above will correct some issues.

Comment: I didn't understand your explanation at first, but then I read up more on setTimeout and have a better understanding. What I'm still not getting is why passing the parameter in the function worked when you were expecting it not to. Any ideas? I want to understand this and correct my code if this is going to cause an issue down the road. Thanks!